66: Luftballons
This is part 66 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
This is a Dosun-Fuwari puzzle. Place some balloons (white circles) and anvils (black circles) into the grid so that every area marked with bolded lines contains exactly one balloon and one anvil. Anvils are “heavy” and fall down; they can only be placed at the bottom of the grid, on top of a black cell or on top of another anvil. Balloons are “light” and go up; they can only be placed at the top of the grid, under a black cell or under another balloon.
Today I have visited a coastal city that offers a nice combination of modern and historical. I have visited museums, gardens and beaches, and spent some time getting to know the history of the local temple which holds great importance to the city and its surrounding areas. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.


Crossword on Penpa+
Dosun-Fuwari on Penpa+ (no answer check)
Across
1. Headwear that's worn by author of message under discussion (3,4)
6. Is the boy of Johnny Cash's offspring? (5)
10. New organisation for Green Party finally getting power (6)
12. Don and Vladimir swapping a bit of information for... nothing (3,2)
13. Long list of books? Whatever! (6)
14. In the end, Egyptians abandoned Anubis, surprising lands along the Nile (5)
15. Blue light source with a hint of white (4)
17. Writer in ecstasy jumping into pool (4)
18. Team gasped audibly (4)
21. Streaming service covering Ono and Lennon's premiere in Honolulu? (4)
23/28. Rapper Pat, for instance – almost like a sort of wolf? (4,6)
25. Voyages to ziggurat location sanctioned at the outset (5)
26. Do pulverize interplanetary visitor (6)
27. Kid's drink that's served hot and very strong (5)
28. (See 23 across)
29. Save second page containing the name of East Asian dictator (5)
30. Jaguar and its ilk described as "life changing" gaming console (7)
Down
1. After a little talk, elephants unexpectedly expressing opinion – at last, they have extraordinary communication skills! (9)
2. I'll get to that right away during monitoring (2,2)
3. Given gentle caresses dancing, tempted to leave man (6)
4. Neapolitan slice eaten by mature Southern woman (5)
5. Rate of rising sea surface in Singapore (5)
7. Poker player (4)
8. One among Dalton, Newton, Tesla, ...? (4)
9. Leaves a cute vase broken (9)
11. Article dives into right and left wing rhetoric (4)
16. Totally crazy fun, lol (4,2)
19. Author, seen with partner and two females, has gone bad (2,3)
20. Match before qualifying rounds (5)
21. Shell city shelled in the 40s (4)
22. I was pulling your leg about the retirement of Colorado athlete (4)
23. Buggy computer memory is under pressure (4)
24. Green 10 across – not about something passed on to the next generation? (4)

Gladys will return in Worship and Wandering.

Clearly this should have been 99 Luftballons ;)

Clue explanations:

 Across:
 1: T(OP)HATS (OP = "original poster", author of message under discussion)
 6. IS+SUE
 10. ENERG*+_Y
 12. PUT(i->O)N
 13. LIT+ANY
 14. NUBIA(-s)*
 15. LE(W_)D
 17. PO(E)T
 18. SIDE ("sighed")
 21. H(-ono,-l_)ULU
 23/28. POSTMA(-n)+LONE
 25. TO+UR+S_
 26. MULL+ET
 27. CHA+FF *(def 'Kid', as in 'tease')
 29. S+KIM+P
 30. FELI*+NES
Down
 1. T_ + ELEPATHS(-n)*
 2. _ON IT_
 3. PETTED(-m)*
 4. AG(N_)E+S
 5. (DEEP+S_)<
 7. STUD ddef
 8. U+N+(I)+T (Dalton = atomic mass unit, abbreviated 'amu' or just 'u')
 9. EVACUATES*
 11. R(AN)T
 16. FULL ON*
 19. I+S.O.+FF
 20. _EQUAL_
 21. HULL (a city that was heavily attacked in WWII)
 22. J(OC<)K
 23. P+RAM
 24. G(-re)EN+E


Dosun-Fuwari solve:

 Note that no 'stacked' anvils or balloons can get through a vertical run of 2 cells in the same region. Therefore any cells between two such runs are empty.


 The middle 4 region now only has two positions, and they can be determined.


 And note that the lower-left region has only one place a balloon can go... the rest of the puzzle is easy to fill.


And in the finished grids,

 
 the letters corresponding to the balloons spell out the city of THIRUVANANTHAPURAM!


rot13(5q vf QRRC< + F. 21q: Uhyy vf gur anzr bs na Ratyvfu pvgl, bs juvpu Jvxvcrqvn fnvgu "Zber guna 95% bs gur pvgl jnf qnzntrq be qrfgeblrq va gur oyvgm".)
